# Get compare product collection on CMS, Catalog Pages

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection, compare

I have used the below code but that is not working on catalog, cms & product page for me. but for compare page, cart page, and checkout page it's working.

```
$objectManager     = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$compare           = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts');
$compareCollection = $compare->getSectionData();
foreach($compareCollection['items'] as $items){
   echo $items['id']."</br>";
}
```

**Note:** I am checking for guest users.

I am in wonder the same code is working for cart & checkout page but I am getting empty collection for cms, catalog and product page.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.!!